# Transposing data in Excel Not Working

Tags: excel, transpose

I have a file from which I copied a big column and tried to paste it in another excel using paste-special "transpose". But I was unable to do the transpose, it gave me an error.

`Error: The information cannot be pasted because the copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape`

Comment: Error: "The information cannot be pasted because the copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape"

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I found an answer. If the number of columns>16384 then we get this.

Comment: We may also get it for many other reasons.. I have posted a generic answer to this question (below).

Comment: There are no rows with more than 16384 columns.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld If a table with 17000 rows and 2 columns was tried to be transposed, then we get this error. As the maximum number of columns on a worksheet is 16,384.

Comment: Absolutely. But you wrote that you copied a large **row**, not that that you copied a large column. Had you written what you had done then the answer would have been more obvious

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sorry, copied column and pasted as row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all the possibilities:

The **maximum number of columns on a worksheet is 16,384** - [Worksheet size:1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns for Excel2010](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmworksheetworkbook). The range you're trying to transpose may have more than 16,384 rows and will thus overflow the maximum number of columns available.

OR

The most likely cause is that you have selected a group of cells to copy and then when you want to paste, you have selected another group of cells that are not the same cell size.

Usually you can **get past this error by selecting only a single cell and pasting to that cell**. The cell you selected will act as the top-left most cell in the pasted selection, or the top most cell if it’s only a single column of data.

OR

However, there is another cause for this error that can be elusive (**Grouping of sheets**).

Check to **make sure that you have not grouped your sheets**. There are a couple of ways to tell.

First, ungrouped sheets are a different color than the selected, active sheet. In the screenshot below, notice the different color between Sheet1 and the other sheets.

[image]

In a grouped set of sheets, notice they are all the same color.

[image]

One other way to tell is to look to the top of your workbook. If you see [Group] beside the workbook name, then you know you have grouped sheets. You can’t copy a single cell from a group of sheets and paste to a workbook cell with non grouped sheets. What Excel is trying to do is copy the cells you selected from not one workbook, but from all of the grouped workbooks, as if they were stacked. Then when you select a single cell in an ungrouped workbook, Excel determines that you are trying to paste the grouped cells into a single cell on a single worksheet and says “*Nope, can’t fit all of that there!*” *Imagine trying to fit a single stack of 100 folded towels into a small suitcase and close the lid.* It would be impossible.

To group worksheets, select a worksheet and then hold the SHIFT key down and select another worksheet. You can also hold down the CTRL key to do a relative selection (you can pick and choose). When multiple sheets are selected in this manner, the sheets are automatically grouped and the [Group] warning appears at the top of the workbook. You can ungroup the sheets by selecting only one of the worksheets in a grouping and the rest will turn the darker color. You can also right click a group of selected sheets and left click the “Ungroup Sheets” option.

Reference : [The information cannot be pasted because the copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/03/14/the-information-cannot-be-pasted-because-the-copy-area-and-the-paste-area-are-not-the-same-size-and-shape/)